# Como incrementar o contador com ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <div ng-if="column.new">
        {{ contador = contador + 1 }}
        <span ng-if="contador === 1">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">TESTDASDALGO</div>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="contador > 1">
            {{ contador = 0 }}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Os valores estão sendo printados entre `colchetes`.

Uma outra dúvida:

- A lógica deve ser feita no front? Tenho muita coisa condicional no meu projeto, provavelmente vai ficar bem confuso... (Há uma outra forma de se fazer)?

É possivel fazer algo parecido com o que escrevi abaixo?

```
var contador = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.columns, function(column){
    if(column.new){
        contador++;
        if(contador === 1){
            include('umarquivo.html');
        }
        if(contador > 1){
            '</div>'; //fechar uma div
            contador = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Não há necessidade de realizar uma operação assim apenas para um contador de linhas, já que o ng-repeat fornece um automaticamente - `$index`:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.paineis = ['aaaaa','bbbbb','ccccc','ddddd','eeeee','fffff']; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div ng-repeat='i in paineis'>{{$index}} - {{i}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

O ng-repeate fornece o índice da iteração, então você pode utilizar essa variável para auxiliar você a resolver o seu problema.

se quiser entender melhor o funcionamento do ng-repeat 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<div ng-repeat="column in columns">
   <div ng-if="column.new">
       <span ng-if="$index === 1">
           <div class="alert alert-danger">TESTDASDALGO</div>
       </span>
    <span ng-if="$index > 1">
        {{ contador = 0 }}
    </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Sempre evite colocar lógica de negócio na view, ela é responsavel pela representação da informação para usuário, procure sempre colocar lógica de views nos controllers